# How to test a log method in catch block in Unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, nunit

I have the following code for which I am writing a unit test

```
    protected virtual string GetTokenFromTheWebrequest(WebRequest httpWebRequestObject)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse responseHttpPostForToken = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequestObject.GetResponse();
            string tokenJson = GetContentResponse(responseHttpPostForToken);
            AccessToken accesstokenObj = DeserializeToAccessToken(tokenJson);
            return accesstokenObj.Token;
        }
        catch (Exception Error)
        {
            Log.Debug("error");//I want to test this method
            throw Error;
        }
    }
```

So,For this I have this unit test

```
     [Test]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(JsonReaderException))]
    public void GetTokenFromTheWebrequestTestwithInValidHttpWebResponseOjectJsonReader()
    {
        var mockHttpWebResponse = new Mock<HttpWebResponse>();
        var mockHttpWebRequest = new Mock<HttpWebRequest>();
        var mockLog = new Mock<ILog>();
        mockHttpWebRequest.Setup(c => c.GetResponse()).Returns(mockHttpWebResponse.Object);
        mockedSurveyMonkeyAPIService.Setup(y => y.GetContentResponse(mockHttpWebResponse.Object)).Returns(TestData.TestData.SampleResponseStream);
        mockedSurveyMonkeyAPIService.Setup(z => z.DeserializeToAccessToken(TestData.TestData.SampleResponseStream)).Throws(new JsonReaderException());
        //mockLog.Setup(x => x.Debug("error")).Throws(new WebException());
        var token = mockedSurveyMonkeyAPIService.Object.GetTokenFromTheWebrequest(mockHttpWebRequest.Object);
        mockLog.VerifySet(x => x.Debug("error"),Times.Once); //its not going till this when i debug
    }
```

Can anyone suggest how to check whether Log.Debug is called properly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be testing any of your own code... you've mocked pretty much everything being used in that method. This begs the question `what is actually being tested` and the answer is that your implementation details are being tested, not any logic. You have even mocked the logger, so really you are testing the .NET try-catch mechanism here.

If you make any minor change to this method, your test will break even though the behaviour is the same. This is not the kind of test you want to shackle yourself to.

There are better ways of testing. For example, if you want to test your logger - test it in isolation of this method so you know your logger works. Don't test the logger by testing calls to it everywhere it is used.

Comment: okay I will test my log function in a separate test method,how should I do that ,I mean what should my test assert statement or verify statement look like.

Comment: What does your logger do / expose?

Comment: I am using log4net, it writes the error message and its details in a  file, do you want more details ?

Comment: Okay, and what do you want to ensure... that you have log4net configured correctly? That would really be an integration test as to really test it you'd have to check the log file.

Comment: I want to check if an exception occurs my log.debug gets called properly,I should check its getting called.